# Minimum window size in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows

Quick question that I cannot find any good answers to: I want my program window to be possible to resize on desktop. But there should be a minimum possible size to the window. How do I set this in .NET MAUI?

For example, with Avalonia, I do this by setting `MinHeight="400"` and `MinWidth="800"` in the XAML properties for `<Window>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the CreateWindow method in the `App.xaml.cs`.

```
 protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
 {
          var window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);
          window.MinimumHeight = 600; // set minimal window height
          window.MinimumWidth = 800; // set minimal window width
          return window;
 }
```